# If the elements of the list point to same memory address, how are the two list not referring to the same object?

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I initialize two lists as follows:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [1]
```

Then I find the memory location of the elements at index 0 for both the lists:

```
>>> id(a[0])
93961440619840
>>> id(b[0])
93961440619840
```

The address of both the element is the same. But when I try to find out if both the lists are referring to the same object, I get 'False'

```
>>> a is b
False
```

My question is, if the elements of the list refers to the same memory, why do the list not refer to the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, if the elements of the list refers to the same memory, why do the list not refer to the same object?

Because lists are mutable objects, so each list literal *has* to create a brand new list object independent from every previous one^[0]. Otherwise

```py
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> print(b)
```

would print `[1]` rather than the empty list, which would be insane.

The reason why `id(a[0])` and `id(b[0])` are the same despite being different literals is that Python *can* preallocate / intern frequently used *immutable* objects to lower memory consumption.

This is an implementation detail which *must not* be relied upon as it's an internal property of a specific implementation *and* it can change at any time. Currently, CPython will preallocate all integers between -5 and 256 (included), so these will always be the same objects even if you create them via independent literals *or via computations*.

[0] technically cpython (again internal detail of a specific implementation) maintains *freelists* of objects, so when a list is "collected" it's really stored away so the allocation can be reused next time we need a list instead of having to reallocate and setup a brand new one. This means different list used consecutively (but not concurrently) can have the same `id`, even if there are lots of other allocations in the meantime.

Comment: In your example, wouldn't it be more efficient in terms of memory if 'a' and 'b' were the same object upon initialization since their elements are none (or same), but when you append 1 to 'a', then 'a' and 'b' becomes different object.

Comment: That can be a strategy behind the scene but it's not observable: in cpython the `id` is actually the position of the object in-memory, modifying the object in-place can not change this information, it can't "reach back" and go update the pointer of all the pointees. So the way to implement this requires that you have different `id` anyway, it's just that both are thin facades to the same underlying thing, then update themselves to something else when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Only the memory location of the elements at index 0 are equal, not the memory address of the whole lists.

```
a[0] is b[0] # This returns True
```

The memory location of the entire lists are different: you can test so by typing

```
id(a)
id(b)
```

Python does so to reduce the memory usage

Answer (score 0):

If you check `a[0] is b[0]` then it will be `True`. Since the element of `a[0]` and `b[0]` are the same and that's why those ids also the same. The result is `True`.

```
a = [1]
b = [1]
print(a[0] is b[0])
print(id(a[0]), id(a[0]))

# Output
# True
# 1793259440 1793259440
```

Now why `a is b` is False? Becasue a and b are distinct list and have distinct id

```
print(a is b)
print(id(a), id(b))

# Output
# False
# 9997064 9997800
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are different objects, so `id(a)` is not equal to `id(b)`

but `a[0]` is **constant** `1`, which equals to `b[0]`, and their addresses are the same, to save memory.

Help this helps.

Comment: Its evident that 'a' and 'b' are different, the question was more towards why are they different even if its elements belong to same memory address

Comment: "a" and "b" are different list object, you can add the same elements into it, but they are two different containers. Even two empty list objects are different, while you can say they both have no elements.